# What personal details are passengers required to provide for travel to or via the United States?

Tags: usa, air-travel, paperwork, privacy

I read on the [KLM website](https://www.klm.com), while booking a flight:

> For travel to or via United States, all passengers need to provide various personal details (such as date of birth) to the authorities.

What personal details are passengers required to provide for travel to or via the United States?

Comment: What an odd thing to mention.  Every traveler presenting a travel document to border control authorities in any country is providing their date of birth to the authorities.

Comment: "This question needs details or clarity.". What details or clarity shall I add?

Comment: "What details or clarity shall I add?" Indeed. I've added my vote to reopen.  The question seems perhaps a bit trivial and the answer perhaps self-evident, but a(s the answer shows) the US collects more information than many would expect, so it is not as trivial or self-evident a matter as some might think.  That the question is short and simple is an advantage, not a deficiency.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Roughly:

- **You yourself** first need to organise that you're allowed entry in the US. When you're not automatically qualified that might mean you'll need to provide all the personal information necessary to **obtain a transit or other visa** and if you're qualified for the visa waiver program you still need obtain an **ESTA** and will need to provide the necessary personal data.
- The **airline needs** to collect (well enough in advance)  enough personalia (from you) to complete the requirements for the *advanced passenger information system* ([APIS](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/travel-industry-personnel/apis2)) and/or the US Customs and Border Patrol (CBP) to know if they can allow you to board.

Typically what the airline is required to provide is a combination of Passenger Name Record (PNR) data , the information found on the front page of your passport and your U.S. destination address.

---

## Passenger Name Record (PNR) data

Source: https://www.cbp.gov/travel/clearing-cbp/passenger-name-record

> ### What information is collected:
>
> PNR information obtained from commercial air carriers and ... may include some combination of the following categories of information, when available:
>
> 1. PNR record locator code.
> 2. Date of reservation/issue of ticket.
> 3. Date(s) of intended travel.
> 4. Name(s).
> 5. Benefit information (i.e., free tickets, upgrades, etc.).
> 6. Other names on PNR, including number of travelers on PNR.
> 7. All available
>    contact information (including originator of reservation).
> 8. All
>    available payment/billing information (e.g. credit card number).
> 9. Travel itinerary for specific PNR.
> 10. Travel agency/travel agent.
> 11. Code
>     share information (e.g., when one air carrier sells seats on another
>     air carrier's flight).
> 12. Split/divided information (e.g., when one PNR
>     contains a reference to another PNR).
> 13. Travel status of passenger
>     (including confirmations and check-in status).
> 14. Ticketing
>     information, including ticket number, one way tickets and Automated
>     Ticket Fare Quote (ATFQ) fields.
> 15. Baggage information.
> 16. Seat
>     information, including seat number.
> 17. General remarks including Other
>     Service Indicated (OSI), Special Service Indicated (SSI) and
>     Supplemental Service Request (SSR) information. Any collected APIS
>     information (e.g., Advance Passenger Information (API) that is
>     initially captured by an air carrier within its PNR, such as
>     passport number, date of birth and gender).
> 18. All historical changes
>     to the PNR listed in numbers 1 to 18.
>
> ***Not all air carriers maintain the same sets of information in PNR, and
> a particular individual’s PNR likely will not include information for
> all possible categories.*** In addition, PNR does not routinely include
> information that could directly indicate the racial or ethnic origin,
> political opinions, religious or philosophical beliefs, trade union
> membership, health, or sex life of the individual. To the extent PNR
> does include terms that reveal such personal matters, DHS employs an
> automated system that filters certain of these terms and only uses
> this information in exceptional circumstances where the life of an
> individual could be imperilled or seriously impaired.

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

---

## Advanced Passenger Information System (APIS)

Source: https://www.cbp.gov/sites/default/files/documents/apis_factsheet_3.pdf

> ### Overview
>
> A new predeparture Advance Passenger Information System (APIS) requirement allows the Department of Homeland Security (DHS) to
> review passenger information prior to boarding for commercial flights
> arriving into or departing from the United States and for commercial
> vessels destined for or departing the United States.
>
> ### Purpose
>
> The advance transmission of this information, coupled with ***[Passenger Name Record (PNR) data](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/clearing-cbp/passenger-name-record)***, will provide DHS the ability to identify potential threats and coordinate with carriers and foreign
> law enforcement to prevent the boarding of a person of interest. APIS
> The Advance Passenger Information System (APIS) is a widely used
> electronic data interchange system that allows carriers to transmit
> traveler data to CBP. APIS data includes **passenger information that
> would be found on the face of a passport, such as full name, gender,
> and country of passport issuance.**

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

- https://www.cbp.gov/travel/travel-industry-personnel/apis2

---

And finally:

- https://www.cbp.gov/travel/travel-industry-personnel/apis/apis-final-rule-reqs

> Carriers should make every effort to ensure the address information they collect and submit to CBP via APIS, is identical to **the U.S. destination address declared to CBP by the passenger** upon application for entry (for I-94 purposes). Carriers should also make every effort to ensure the address submitted in the APIS manifest appears to be a valid address.
>
> Below is clarification on what information should be included on the manifest for those passengers who are: (1) visiting the US; (2) joining a cruise ship; (3) picking up a rental car or; (4) those not knowing their address while in the United States:
> ...

Comment: "you'll need to provide all the personal information necessary to obtain a transit or other visa": not if you're a citizen of the US, Canada, or Bermuda, and not if the flight is passing through US airspace without landing.  Also, APIS includes more information than that found in the passport, for example (for most passengers) a US address.

Comment: I'm quite certain APIS also includes visa details, passport number, birth date, and other items that are not listed in your answer.

Comment: @littleadv the citation is what it is and *"passenger information that would be found on the face of a passport"* includes all of that  except visa details. - - I would assume that visa details get retrieved using such personalia rather than relying on what either passengers or airlines report though...